# Boot sequence unlike reboot

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

When I turn on the computer it acts very differently than when I reboot it.

[WinXP Pro, Intel Core2 6600, 2.4GHZ, 2GB RAM, NVIDA GeForce]

Boot:

- Monitor must be plugged into the motherboard or no image.
- Screen resolution 800x600.
- Changes to the resolution cause only the top half of the screen to be usable, and are lost when I shut down the computer.
- Desktop icons arranged in neat rows on left of desktop.
- Nothing of note in system tray
- In Device Manger -> Display adapter: Intel(R) Q965/Q963 Express Chipset Family
- In Device Manger -> Monitors, two monitors are listed
- Hibernate and standby work.

Reboot:

- Monitor must be plugged into the graphics card or no image.
- Screen resolution - 1280x1024
- Desktop icons arranged in the cute circle that I put them in.
- NVIDIA icon shows in system tray.
- In Device Manger -> Display adapter: NVIDA GeForce 6200LE
- In Device Manger -> Monitors, one monitor is listed
- **Hibernate and standby do not work.**
- When awakened after a hibernation it says:

  > The system could not be restarted from its previous location because the restoration image is corrupt.  Delete restoration data & proceed to system boot?

Double reboot (inconsistent):

- Monitor must be plugged into the graphics card.
- Screen resolution - 1024x768
- Odd icon shows in system tray whose tooltip says "Intel Graphics"

For a while my morning ritual was to boot, wait, reboot using (alt+ctrl+del -> ctrl+u -> R), wait. Keeping the monitor plugged into the graphics card.

But aside for the inefficiency of this method, I sometimes want to standby and can't.

On the other hand, the computer is unusable when set to 800x600.

Please help, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas regarding the video problem:

1. Ensure that you have the latest version of DirectX
2. Ensure that you have the latest video drivers from the manufacturer's site
3. Start menu->Run, type "msconfig", select tab "Boot" and in "Boot Options" uncheck "Base video".
4. Right-click the desktop, Settings, Advanced, click on the "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display" and select a screen resolution.
5. If the secondary display is detected as Generic non-PnP monitor, try to find drivers for this model, or manually install the Generic PnP one.
6. Boot in Safe mode : If this doesn't happen then the cause might be some installed application
7. Create a new user account to work with (sometimes this solves the problem).

Comment: 1. Done, DX11. 2.Done. 3. Base Video was already unchecked. 4. It was already checked. 5. Can you a bit more descriptive. 6 & 7 will be after reboot.

Comment: Do you use one or two monitors?

Comment: There is a driver from 2009.10.05 for your model here : http://www.nvidia.com/object/winxp_191.07_whql.html.

Comment: @brandstaetter - one monitor.  @harrymc - why didn't Windoze find that?! I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @samgoody: MS drivers are not necessarily the same as the manufacturer.

Comment: I updated the NVIDIA driver and DX11, no luck. 
The switch of screens (graphics card / motherboard) shows in the monitor splash and boot screens, long before Windows begins to load.  How can safe mode fix that. [I tried anyways, no luck]. On original boot, where it claims two monitors, they are identical "Plug & Play Monitors" on "q945 chipset"

Comment: If this happens in Safe mode boot+reboot, then Windows is guilty. In this mode only Microsoft drivers are used (you might do well to verify that Nvidia is really unused in this case). This means that there is no solution, except for desperate measures like reinstalling Windows (which might still end up with the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the system BIOS if the on-board graphics card is disabled if you are not using it.

Check the first messages that appear when you start your machine to see how to enter the BIOS (usually `Del`, `F1`, `F10` or another function key)

Comment: I've gone through the BIOS, and didn't see anything that would hint at whether the on-board is being used or not.  Besides, isn't the BIOS run on reboot as well?

Comment: Yes, but maybe there's a "race condition" on cold boot, where the on-board card gets power first and registers itself, but when the system is rebooted (warmstart), the extra graphics card is already initialized and manages to register itself first. Did you build this system yourself or buy it ready made?

Comment: I bought it from a shop that built it. They could not fix it though :(  How to check out these hypothesis?

Comment: If the computer starts to behave once you remove the extra graphics card, you have found the culprit. It will be hard to diagnose it remotely. Do you have a manual for the motherboard? Perhaps there is a DIP switch or something directly on the motherboard to deactivate the onboard graphics.

Comment: @brandstaetter. The monitor must already be plugged into the onboard[startup], or graphics board[reboot] in order to show the boot sequence and monitor splash screen.  How could creating a new user in Windows - which happens much later - change that?

Comment: @samgoody I never said anything about creating a user.